# How does a buffered reader know what line to read?

Tags: java, android, http, inputstream, bufferedreader

In a while/for loop we use buffered readers, then we append it into a string builder. But wont the same line get read over again & again as we are not providing some line reference numbers.

Additional Details: The buffered reader is wrapped in a Input Stream Reader,I am talking about Java(Android)

```
    String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                output.append(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
```

Comment: Always paste your actual code instead of trying to describe it. And please clarify your question.

Comment: ok, I will paste it .

Comment: -2 Downvotes , whats wrong?

Comment: Objects can carry state. The reader stores where it is in the file.

Comment: Every call to [`readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--) will .... wait for it .... read one line from the underlying `Reader`. Let me be explicit: It read the **next** line from the `Reader`. What else would it read?

Comment: It reads the *next* line. The operating system knows where the process is up to in the file. Otherwise sequential I/O would be impossible,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read a file there is a pointer which points to the next read position in the file. Every time you call `readLine` the pointer move on until it sees a `\r\n` or `\n`. Then the pointer stays here for your next read.